# order a string like a number, in Nhibernate

Tags: mysql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a field that is a string instead of an int, solely because there may be cases like this:

```
1, 2, 3, 3A, 5, 6 ...
```

Now, the orderby works fine, in a way, but not as expected:

```
1
10
11
111
12
2
20
3
```

Anyone have an idea of doing this? My DB is `MySQL`. I noticed this solution on other questions..

```
ORDER BY category_id + 0
```

How can I implement that in Fluent Nhibernate?

**EDIT**

To clarify, the required order should be:

```
1
2
3
3A
10
11
12
20
111
...
```

**EDIT 2**

Also take note that it might not only be 3A, it could have more inputs too eg: 3B, 3C.

The order would then be:

```
1
2
3
3A
3B
3C
10
11
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map this column twice. Once fully for all operations. Once only for "Select" and Ordering.
In **XML** mapping it would look like this: (the column name is [**AsNumber**])

```
<property name="AsString" column="AsNumber"  />
<property name="AsNumber"  insert="false" update="false" 
 formula="(CAST ( CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC([AsNumber]) &lt;&gt; 0 THEN [AsNumber] ELSE '99999999' END  as int))"
/>
```

The syntax I used is from MS SQL Server. It tries to solve cases like '**3A**' above. It will be simply converted to some large value...

Notice that the 'AsNumber' has insert and update set to false.
and the C# class snippet:

```
public virtual string AsString { get; set; }
public virtual int AsNumber { get; set; }
```

I've tested it and it is working. I am sure that to use similar in fluent won't take you long...

Comment: 3A shouldn't be at the back. amended my qn.

Comment: I would say that key point is: now you have a clue how to do that. The main trick is to introduce the second mapping, without updates and inserts. This property can be then used for **Ordering**. How the final syntax will look like inside the **IF** clause is up to your further tuning ...

Comment: For example, you can convert chars to ASCII codes and append them as decimal parts... I am sure that you will find better algorithm for your needs than me ;)... Well, you know how to map it, and I believe that this could help you. Does it make sense?

Comment: @RadimKöhler. I am guessing the op does not do hbm files and needs a fluent nhib equivalent, if there is one. +1 from me tho

Comment: Created a solution based on your analysis of adding another property specially for ordering. marked your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a formula field something like

```
Map(x => x.MyColumnAsNumber).Formula("CAST(MyColumn AS int)");
```

And then order by that field.